# neo4j cypher query to get a sequence of nodes having same sequence id in the relationship property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find all sequence of nodes with their names occurring in a list and having the same sequence id exits in the relationship in between. for eg: based on the graph constructed from the query below:

```
MERGE (a:Person { name:  'graph'}) 
MERGE (b:Person { name:  'server' }) 
MERGE (a)-[:NEXT{seqid:1}]->(b)

MERGE (c:Person { name:  'server' }) 
MERGE (d:Person { name:  'db'}) 
MERGE (c)-[:NEXT{seqid:1}]->(d)

MERGE (a1:Person { name:  'graph'}) 
MERGE (b:Person { name:  'db' }) 
MERGE (a)-[:NEXT{seqid:2}]->(b)

MERGE (c:Person { name:  'db' }) 
MERGE (d:Person { name:  'server'}) 
MERGE (c)-[:NEXT{seqid:2}]->(d)
```

find all sequences of nodes with their names in the given list , say ['graph','server','db'] with same 'seqid' property exists in the relationship in between.

i.e.

```
(graph)->(server)-(db) with same seqid :1

(graph)->(db)->(server) with same seqid :1   //there can be another matching
                                               sequence with same seqid

(graph)->(db)->(server) with same seqid :2
```

Is there a way to keep only the final sequence of nodes say ' (graph)->(server)->(db)' for each sequences instead of each of the subpath of a large sequence like (graph)->(server) or (server)->(db)

pls help me to solve this.........

(I am using neo4j 2.3.6 community edition via java api in embedded mode..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get all the possible paths
MATCH path = (S:Person)-[rels:NEXT*]->(E:Person)

    // Check that the property is the same
    WHERE ALL( r in rels WHERE rels[0]['seqid'] = r.seqid )

RETURN rels[0]['seqid'] as seqid,
       // Get an array of names 
       REDUCE(acc = [], n in nodes(path) | acc + [n.name])

ORDER BY seqid, 
      length(path)
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep only the final sequence of nodes say ' (graph)->(server)->(db)'  for each sequences instead of each of the subpath of a large sequence like (graph)->(server) or (server)->(db)